# AWS Autoscaling, Launch new instance with current version of AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling

In autoscaling group I have four machines. I have modified or added few changes on the instance and took IMAGE/AMI. If load increase autoscaling will add new instances. Now, I want new launched instances with latest AMI. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Your AMI is associated at the Launch Configuration level. You have to update your Launch Configuration to point out to the new AMI you created. Then you associate your new LC with your AutoScalingGroup.

Comment: Technically, you have to copy your existing LC to a new one. LCs cannot be edited/updated.

Comment: @thomas-l Thanks a lot